# Switching sprite positions with each other

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have 6 sprites that I want to switch positions with each other every time a function is called. I also don't want any two (or more) sprites to ever be in the same position. I tried using this function but it didn't do anything.

```
func newPositionPipe() {
    let pipePosition1 = CGPoint(x: 63, y: 1275)
    let pipePosition2 = CGPoint(x: 188, y: 1275)
    let pipePosition3 = CGPoint(x: 315, y: 1275)
    let pipePosition4 = CGPoint(x: 443, y: 1275)
    let pipePosition5 = CGPoint(x: 565, y: 1275)
    let pipePosition6 = CGPoint(x: 687, y: 1275)

    var randomNumberBetween0And6 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))

    let pipePositions = [pipePosition1, pipePosition2, pipePosition3, pipePosition4, pipePosition5, pipePosition6]

    greenPipe.position = pipePositions[randomNumberBetween0And6]
    redPipe.position = pipePositions[randomNumberBetween0And6]
    greenPipe.position = pipePositions[randomNumberBetween0And6]
    yellowPipe.position = pipePositions[randomNumberBetween0And6]
    greyPipe.position = pipePositions[randomNumberBetween0And6]
    purplePipe.position = pipePositions[randomNumberBetween0And6]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it setup now will make every pipe position the same because it will be referencing the same random `index` number you've generated with `randomNumberBetween0And6`. Put this in a loop and generate a new random number each time. You could also use a [Tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329) to swap the values.

```
(greenPipe.position, redPipe.position) = (redPipe.position, greenPipe.position)
```